# To skip DIV from Tab Navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

My HTML code is mentioned below. It is working fine on IE and chrome
browser. But in Mozilla, when focus occurs on DIV having class=""mejs-
button mejs-volume-button mejs-mute" it selects the unwanted width.

Is it possible that on Tab press focus only occurs on Anchor elements and 
we can skip main outer DIV. I have tried by using Tabindex="-1". But then 
focus will not reflect on anchor elements.Issue occurring only in latest Mozilla. 
The issue is related to HTML5 Video plugin. I have used 'mediaelementplayer-min.js'.

```
 <div class="mejs-button mejs-volume-button mejs-mute">

    <button type="button" aria-controls="mep_0" title="Mute" 
    aria-label="Mute"></button>
    <a tabindex="0" role="slider" aria-valuetext="10%" aria-valuenow="10" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-label="volumeSlider" style="display: none;" href="javascript:void(0);" class="mejs-volume-slider">

    <span class="mejs-offscreen">Use Up/Down Arrow keys to increase or 
   decrease volume.</span>
    <div class="mejs-volume-total"></div>
    <div style="height: 10.3833px; top: 97.6167px;"class="mejs-volumme-current"></div>
    <div style="top: 95px;" class="mejs-volume-handle"></div></a>
    </div>
```

Comment: Could you confirm *mejs* is for [mediaElementsJS](http://mediaelementjs.com/) please?

Comment: @JeffNoel you are right. Link is correct.